# Как учить SWIFT без Mac'а?

Tags: windows, ios, swift, macos

Ничто не помешает мне учить синтаксис языка с помощью различных онлайн компиляторов.
Однако, насколько я понимаю, при попытке создать даже самое простенькое приложение, где нужен полноценный проект с файлами итд всё остановится, тк вряд ли такое возможно на каких-либо онлайн-песочницах.

Учить синтаксис вхолостую без дальнейшей возможности практики на проектах я не вижу смысла, хотя желание попробовать себя в ios-разработке есть.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли какое-то решение моей проблемы кроме виртуалки с мак ос? (попробовал, мой пк почему то абсолютно не вывозит - даже банальный хеллоу ворлд в xcode playground долго грузится и впоследствии крашится)

p.s. у меня windows 7/10

Comment: [Swift playground](https://www.apple.com/swift/playgrounds/) можно также на айпаде запускать

Comment: а хакинтошные сборки на голое железо ещё есть или уже только на вируталке можно запустить?

Comment: Хакинтош ставьте или докупайте оперативки чтоб отрезать в виртуалку хотяб 8Г

Answer (score 1):

Компиляторы Swift (официальные) доступны и на Windows, и на Linux, и на macOS последних версий. Так что собирать и запускать программы на Swift вполне можно без мака.

Другое дело, что на Windows и Linux недоступны UI-библиотеки UIKit, SwiftUI и AppKit, которые используются для построения пользовательских интерфейсов в приложениях на iOS и macOS. То есть выучить язык вы сможете, но разобраться в повседневных инструментах - нет.